# Visual Studio 2013 has no SQL Server CE Data Provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2013

I would like create an ADO.NET Entity Model from an existing SQL Server CE database. But when I want to `Generate Database from Model`, there is no list of SQLite provider. Only have the ones for SQL Server. I have installed the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1?SRC=VSIDE) and the [sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.89.0.exe](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.89.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.89.0.exe) already. What is wrong! Did I miss something?

thanks, stevo

Comment: Sqlite is not sql server compact...

Comment: This scenario is currently broken is VS 2013 anyway

Comment: Erik, is this scenario planned to be repaired eventually? I'm kinda stuck right now without it.

Comment: This scenario is supported in the SQL CE Toolbox for SQL Compact 4.0

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's not there. If you'd like to regain the SQLServerCE functionality on your VS2013 you can install the SQL Server Compact Toolbox:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1

Comment: this doesn't bring back the data provider or entity framework support for ce though, so I'm trying to figure out what the benefit is?

Comment: The latest version brings back full EF support for Sql Ce http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/117615